# Looking to monitor and manage SEO for multiple web sites

Tags: seo, optimization

Can anyone suggest a web site or service which will allow me to sign up all my client web sites to manage and monitor their SEO?

I checked out DIYSEO.com that someone suggested. Any reviews on this site?

Comment: What do you mean by the a-lot-generic SEO?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at seomoz.org, i think quite allot of the other seo sas type services run off their api, i all really depends what your looking for if you just want to track serp rankings over time and want to keep it cheap you could use this script from code canyon - http://codecanyon.net/item/complete-google-bing-serp-rank-tracker/2338178?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=jdgower